# Google API Developer token error relating to project

Tags: oauth2-playground

Keep getting this error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", 
    "message": "The caller does not have permission", 
    "code": 403, 
    "details": [
      {
        "errors": [
          {
            "errorCode": {
              "authorizationError": "DEVELOPER_TOKEN_PROHIBITED"
            }, 
            "message": "Developer token is not allowed with project '407408718192'."
          }
```

Did try to refresh developer token and create new project + added relevant client id and secret client id + developer token in OAuth, but I get stopped here for some reason?

I don't know which project the above ID refers to but it doesn't match any of my defined projects.